# Space ignored after backslash?

Tags: c, c11

I'm having difficulties understanding why compiling following program fails

```
// This is comment \ 
int main(void) {
        return 0;
}
```

Notice there is space (0x20) after the `\` character. Compilation fails with

```
+   $ gcc test.c -std=c11 -pedantic
test.c:3:2: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘return’
    3 |  return 0;
      |  ^~~~~~
test.c:4:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
    4 | }
      | ^
```

and I don't understand why. Reading the C11 standard (well, latest draft), section 5.1.1.2 point 2 states that (emphasis mine)

> Each  instance  of  a  backslash  character  (\)  **immediately  followed  by  a  new-linecharacter**  is  deleted,  splicing  physical  source  lines  to  form  logical  source  lines.Only the last backslash on any physical source line shall be eligible for being partof such a splice.  A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character,which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any suchsplicing takes place.

What am I missing? Is this behaviour according to standard? gcc and clang both behave the same way (clang prints warning though). Can I rely on any conforming compiler behaving the same way?

Comment: GCC has a bug/feature that tries to treat backslash near (but not at) the end of a line followed by white space as if the space was not there.  Note that in this context, `'\r'` (CR, carriage return, as in DOS-style CRLF line endings) are treated quite sensibly, but the space instead of CR is perhaps less defensible.

Comment: Seems like an oversight in the standard. It's not a problem with C-style comments `/* comment */`. When C++ comments were added, they obviously missed the interaction with line splicing. As currently written, the standard specifies that line splicing occurs before comment removal. So using C++ style comments to comment out lines ending with a backslash should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the newline is also escaped. When I try compiling on MacOS I get these warnings :

```
t.c:1:20: warning: backslash and newline separated by space
      [-Wbackslash-newline-escape]
// This is comment \
                   ^
t.c:1:21: warning: multi-line // comment [-Wcomment]
// This is comment \
                    ^
```

so this part :

```
int main(void) {
```

is also commented. You're left with

```
    return 0;
}
```

and the compiler doesn't even have time to reach the orphan `}`, it's shouting at the sight of a `return` statement outside a function.